# Protractor Test fail with Appium regarding "Sign in to Chrome" page is displayed

Tags: android, protractor, appium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem running my protractor tests on my real Android Device. It always shows the "Sign in to Chrome.." (see Screenshot) page and my test fail due to that. Is there a possibility to avoid this screen?

[image]